# XAMARIN.FORMS: FCM Push Notifications won't vibrate if app is in background in Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin.Forms but I'm having a few problems handling push notifications. **They only work fine when app is in foreground.**

When the app is in background, all notifications are received and displayed correctly but I can't manage to get them to vibrate or even turn led on. I have found a lot of documentation but it's pretty old and most of the time, methods referred are deprecated.

Anyway, I have a *FirebaseMessagingService* to handle FCM events and this is the action that generates the push notification:

```
    void SendNotification(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);

        intent.PutExtra("type", message.Data["type"]);

        var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(NotificationService);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = null;

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            var importance = NotificationImportance.Default;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("ID", "Name", importance);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ApplicationContext, notificationChannel.Id);
        }
        else
            builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(ApplicationContext);

        builder = builder
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon)
            .SetDefaults((int)((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate))
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentTitle(message.GetNotification().Title)
            .SetContentText(message.GetNotification().Body)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetLights(65536, 1000, 500)
            .SetVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000 })
            .SetPriority((int)NotificationPriority.High);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(PowerService);

        WakeLock wl = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "TAG");

        wl.Acquire(15000);

        notificationManager.Notify(0, builder.Build());

        wl.Release();

    }
```

I also added these lines in the Android.Manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

**It was pretty much simpler before** but I've been adding new things trying to make it work, like the WAKE_LOCK section or the distinction of Android Version when creating the Builder object. **It vibrates only when app is in foreground.**

I even tried using the James Montemagno's Vibrate Plugin or using Android.Vibrator class and they didn't work either when app is in background.

I'm open to suggestions here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Oreo(+), you have to enable the vibration on the `NotificationChannel` via `EnableVibration(true)`.

#### Oreo Example:

```
NotificationChannel channel;
channel = notificationManager.GetNotificationChannel(myUrgentChannel);
if (channel == null)
{
    channel = new NotificationChannel(myUrgentChannel, channelName, NotificationImportance.High);
    channel.EnableVibration(true);
    channel.EnableLights(true);
    channel.SetSound(
        RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification),
        new AudioAttributes.Builder().SetUsage(AudioUsageKind.Notification).Build()
    );
    channel.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;
    notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
}
channel.Dispose();
```

Comment: I added the calls to enable vibration and lights in Oreo but still doesn't work. It doesn't vibrate when app is in background. Maybe I'm missing something else but I can't tell what could it be :(

Answer (score 1):

*After reviewing everything over and over again all I needed was adding this to the payload. I didn't know this must be included in order for it to vibrate. I wasn't able to modify this behavior programmatically but I'm sure it's possible.*

```
   "notification":{
       "sound":"default"
    }
```

**FOUND IT HERE**
[Vibration on push-notification not working when phone locked/app not open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45588629/vibration-on-push-notification-not-working-when-phone-locked-app-not-open)