# AppCenter Push to Xamarin.Forms Android no vibration

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, push-notification, vibration, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using AppCenter Push to send notification to my Xamarin.Forms (iOS & Android) application. I received the notification successfully. However, on Android, when the app is at the background, the phone will not vibrate even I have turn on vibration from the phone setting. iOS is having both sound and vibration.

I have followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/xamarin-forms and implemented the payload as below.

```
{
    "notification_target": {
        "type": "devices_target",
        "devices": [
            "XXX",
            "YYY"
        ]
    },
    "notification_content": {
        "name": "default",
        "title": "",
        "body": "ABC",
        "sound":"default",
        "custom_data": {
            "Title": "",
            "Message": "ZZZ",
            "badge": "100",
            "sound": "default"
        }
    }
}
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.xxx.yyy" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="78" android:versionName="5.0.4">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <application android:label="ParentsApp" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@drawable/logo_1024">
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/red" />
  </application>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.xxx.yyy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.xxx.yyy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

</manifest>
```

iOS - Got sound and vibration

Android - Got default sound but no vibrate

May I know is it something need to add in for Android? Thank you.

Comment: Did you EnableVibration in code behind and add user-permission in Manifest as mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49282741/xamarin-forms-fcm-push-notifications-wont-vibrate-if-app-is-in-background-in-a)?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I think I did. I just added my manifest into the question. Thanks.

Comment: To enable the vibrate, you can read [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/notifications/local-notifications#enabling-sound-and-vibration) in document. While it may also caused by settings of different Android devices. You can create a local notification with sound and vibrate to check if the vibrate is working.

Comment: But the notification that I'm referring to is when my app is in background, in which Android show the notification which is beyond my control. I could call the Xamarin.Essentials.Vibrate within my app and it does vibrate without issue.

Comment: Well, if the notification is beyond your control, I guess the vibration is be controlled by the device. I've read through the document of AppCenter notification and did not find a method for you to custom the vibration. I will update you if I find something.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT thanks a lot for the help. On native Android, which I did before, is usually handled on onMessageReceived by creating notification channel and manager. Maybe similar to what you have suggested. But I'm not sure if that's the only way to do it as I try to keep it as clean as possible since it's PCL project. And I'm not sure how to do it using onMessageReceived neither with Xamarin.Form.